# XML Deserializing a List<>

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have managed to serialize a list of objects of type Word using XML Serialization:

```
public static void WriteXML(string fileName)
{     
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Word));
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
        fileName);
    foreach (var word in Words)
    {
        writer.Serialize(file, word);
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

I have a problem with deserializing this list. Im using this code snippet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms172872.aspx

I changed my code to something like that:

```
public static void ReadXML(string fileName)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader =
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Word));
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(
        fileName);
    foreach (????)
    {
        Word word=new Word();
        word = (Word) reader.Deserialize(file);
        Words.Add(word); //Words is a List<Word>
    }
}
```

Of course the foreach() loop is not used properly here. I just have no clue how to do this.

Comment: I'm curious:  What does the generated XML look like after the serialization code runs?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Word xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Native>s2</Native>
  <Translation>a1</Translation>
  <Level>0</Level>
</Word><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Word xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Native>s2</Native>
  <Translation>a2</Translation>
  <Level>0</Level>
</Word><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: That is not well-formed XML (note the multiple XML declarations). This XML wouldn't deserialize anyway.

Answer (score 1):

How can you serialize individual `Word` object to same file? This is a kind of overriding the file on each iteration. Simply just serialize the `Database` object instead of separate `Word` objects this way:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
    new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Database));
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName);
writer.Serialize(file, yourDatabaseObject);
```

Note: In addition, make sure that `Database` is marked with `Serializable` attribute.

Comment: In my code there is a Word class and a Database class which has a property: public static List<Word> Words { get; set; }. Do I have to create a new class to mark Words [Serializable]? Or should I mark Database with this attribute?

Comment: In this case better go with Database class since you cannot mark Words serializable because its a property.

Comment: -1 a) You serialize `Words` (Which is List<Word>) but create serializer with `typeof(Word)` b) `Serializable` attribute is not required for XmlSerialization

Comment: @ŁukaszKastelik, Please update the question with full information regarding Database object as well. Which you mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not serialize each word one by one. This would result in a single file containing many xmls, which would of course be invalid.

You want to serialize `Words` (which is `List<Word>`) . Therefore your serializer creation should be `new  XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Word>))`  and serialization as `writer.Serialize(file, Words);`

So your code can be like this:

```
List<Word> Words = ........

WriteXML("a.xml", Words);
var newWords = ReadXML<List<Word>>("a.xml");
```

---

```
public static void WriteXML(string fileName,object obj)
{
    using (var f = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        ser.Serialize(f, obj);
    }
}

public static T ReadXML<T>(string fileName)
{
    using (var f = File.Open(fileName,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(f);
    }
}
```

---

PS: `Serializable` attribute is required only for `BinaryFormatter`. XmlSerializer doesn't need it.

You can find the details of the attributes XmlSerializer uses [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14064/Using-the-XmlSerializer-Attributes)